# Exporting the C# Unitest Results to a Textfile

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, soap, automated-tests

I am Fresher in c# testing.. I am writing unit tests for web services testing. I have added a service reference to the C# unit tests solution and started consuming the classes in the web services for the testing. I have also added an Excel file to provide unit test values.

Below is a example about what I was doing before

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc"
 ,"Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=|DataDirectory|\\TestData.xlsx;defaultdir=C:\\TestData;driverid=1046;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5"
 ,"Sheet1$"
 ,DataAccessMethod.Sequential)
 ,DeploymentItem("TestProject1\\TestData.xlsx")
 ,Owner("")
 ,Description("")
 ,TestMethod()]
public void test1()
{
    try
    {
        var Service = new Service.ServiceClient();
        var Cid = testContextInstance.DataRow["CId"].ToString();
        var MNumber = testContextInstance.DataRow["MNumber"].ToString();
        var VID = testContextInstance.DataRow["VID"].ToString();
        var isVisit = new Service.ISVisit()
        {
            CID = Cid,
            MNum = MNumber,
            VCode = VID
        };

    var first = Service.Medis(isVisit).Cast<Service.ISMedi>().FirstOrDefault();
    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("12345678", first.Proc.ProcID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        if (ex1.InnerException != null)
            Debug.WriteLine(ex1.InnerException.Message);
        Assert.Fail(ex1.Message);
    }
}
```

.Medis()`,`IsVisit` are classes in the services.i am using excel sheet to provide values for the untitest.

[image]

And the unit is passed

[image]

Now the requirement is to Export this test results to a Txt file or CSV or Excel file in this order

Test 1 : Test result + Duration + Output Soap Message.

Test 2 : Test result + Duration + Output Soap Message.

Test 3 : Test result + Duration + Output Soap Message.

Please help me with this. I am using Visual Studio team system to write the unittests .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options are available.

Visual Studio produces a XML result set for each test run (all tests run in a single execution). The results are placed in the TestResults folder at the root of the solution and the file extension is TRX. The test run will contain durations and the status of the tests but it will not contain the SOAP response. If this is sufficient, you could use a simple XSLT transformation to convert the XML to CSV. Alternatively, you can export the test results as a CSV directly from within Visual Studio -- the test results window has a small icon to import/export test results.

If you need the SOAP response, Visual Studio doesn't have anything native within the test runner for this. Your best bet is to append to a log file while the test is running, though what you log (including test duration) is up to you.